# WD portable hardrive My Passport 1TB

Tags: external-hard-drive

I have an issue with my WD Passport 1TB. I have set up security password before I can access actual data. when clicked to open the file "WD Drive Unlock.exe" it shows strange behaviour and it's getting cycled, shows busy, but won't open a window for the password. When I checked the Windows Task Manager, it shows processes are constantly increasing.
Any idea how to fix/replace/restore the file?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried contacting Western Digital?

Comment: Not really as the product is already out of warranty

Comment: It doesn't need to be in warranty, just have them e-mail you a proper copy of "WD Drive Unlock.exe" for your model

Comment: Ok I just created a case at WD Support, let's see if anyone reply. Thanks for advice.

Comment: I'd also give it a shot on another computer, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to try:

Open a support case with WD - which you say you have already done or Try on another PC as suggested by Arthur (It could be a problem with your PC).

In addition to this:

- Try disabling your antivirus?  This wouldn't be the firs time AV took a dislike to programs related to encryption!
- Linux Live CD plus WINE.  Sounds weird, but I once hit a problem where I couldn't unlock an encrypted drive and (as a last resort) booted to a Ubuntu LiveCD, Launched WINE and the app ran!

Hope you get it figured out!